# Return JsonResponse from function in Django REST

Tags: django

I have a query in which all fields are required. I want to make sure they're full. It turns out a lot of duplicate code. So I decided to create a function to which I pass values from a field. But the request continues rather than sending a response code 400.

**My views.py**

```
def pay(request):
    body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    if not body:
        return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'failed',
            'errors': {
                'code': 400,
                'message': 'empty query'
            },
        })
    body = json.loads(body)
    phone = body.get('phone')
    amount = body.get('amount')
    merch_name = body.get('merchant_name')
    #check_field(phone)
    if not phone:
        return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'failed',
            'errors': {
                'code': 400,
                'message': 'phone field is empty'
            },
        })
    if not amount:
        return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'failed',
            'errors': {
                'code': 400,
                'message': 'amount field is empty'
            },
        })
    if not merch_name:
        return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'failed',
            'errors': {
                'code': 400,
                'message': 'merch_name field is empty'
            },
        })
```

**My function:**

```
def check_field(field):
    if not field:
        logger.info('its work')
        return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'failed',
            'errors': {
                'code': 400,
                'message': '{} field is empty'.format(field)
            },
        })
```

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your `check_field` does not work as is, because `field` refers to the value not the name of the variable you pass in.

Using exceptions avoids code duplication:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def pay(request):
    try
        body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        if not body:
            raise ValidationError('empty query')
        body = json.loads(body)
        for field_name in ['phone', 'amount', 'merchant_name']:
            check_field(body, field_name)
    except ValidationError as error:
        return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'failed',
            'errors': {
                'code': 400,
                'message': error.message
            },
        })

 def check_field(data, field_name):
     if not data.get(field_name):
         raise ValidationError('{} field is empty'.format(field_name)
```

I second the suggestion of @youngminz to look into Django REST Framework serializers. Alternatively, you can also use a regular Django form.

If `amount` is a number and 0 is a valid value, you have to use `data.get(field_name) is None` for the check.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is almost right, but it should return a `JsonResponse` object if `check_field` function call's return value is not `None`. (If the function call does not return any value, it actually return `None`)

```
def pay(request):
    ...
    check_result = check_field(phone)
    if check_result is not None:
        return check_result
    ... (repeat ...)
```

Anyway, I suggest you should try Django REST Framework's [Serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). It makes these parameter checking problems easily.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the returned value from the called function (`check_field(phone)`) is not propagated beyond the caller -- the `pay` function. It's `pay` method's responsibility to take decisions based on the return from `check_field`.

You have a couple of options:

- keep the earlier long function with a helper function that gets you you the `JsonResponse` for the passed field e.g.:

  ```
  def get_400_response(field_name):
      return JsonResponse({
          'status': 'failed',
          'errors': {
              'code': 400,
              'message': f'{field_name} can not be empty'
          },
      })
  ```

  and from the `pay` function e.g.:

  ```
  if not phone:
      return get_400_response('phone')  # note the `return` here
  ```
- if you want to use `check_field`, you can either keep it as is and then check from `pay` that if the return is a `JsonReponse`, if so return, otherwise save it as a valid value:

  ```
  phone = body.get('phone')
  if isinstance(phone, JsonResponse):
      return phone
  ```
- Another option would be to raise an exception e.g. `ValidationError` from the `check_field` function, and rather than doing `isinstance` check, handle that in a `try`-`except`, so essentially duck-typing.

---

**Better approach:** *it would be a better idea to accumulate all the errors from all fields and send them as a single response, it increases usability.* So you can create a function that do the validations solely (leveraging other tiny functions as needed) and send either the validated data or a `ValidationError` for invalid data, and you can handle it from `pay`.